# Выбор CMS для интеграции в существующий ASP.NET MVC проект

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, cms, .net

Существует крупный проект на ASP MVC (в сфере электронной коммерции). Необходимо внедрить в неёё систему управления контентом (CMS) для возможности хранить, редактировать и публиковать новости а также добавления мультиязычности на сайт.

Помогите, пожалуйста, выбрать существующую CMS для решения (CMS должна быть на ASP).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ни одна из существующих CMC не даст Вам такой возможности. Одно дело собирать страницы, другое интеграция приложенний для совместной работы. Это всё равно, что пытаться поставить двигатель одной машины на совсем другую. Либо вам придётся подогнать свой сайт под конкретную CMS, т.е. собрать его в этой CMS. Либо писать свою CMS, что ещё сложнее. Одним словом нужно много поработать.

Comment: Не согласен. Продукты на рынке есть на любой вкус. Посмотрите на Радолёт Снегирь и поймете, что новые продукты работают на будущее. Не отставайте :)

Answer (score 2):

[Orchard CMS](http://www.orchardproject.net/)

> Orchard is a free, open source, community-focused Content Management System built on the ASP.NET MVC platform.

Answer (score 2):

[KooBoo CMS](http://www.kooboo.com/)

> Free and open source enterprise level CMS

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще [N2](http://n2cms.com/), [Kentico](http://www.kentico-cms.ru/), [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/), [MonoX](http://monox.mono-software.com/). Посмотрите, может что и подойдет